# In OSX the cursor often covers a tool tip you want to see. Is the orientation of the cursor able to be modified?

Tags: macos, mouse-cursor, tooltip

In OSX, the "hand" cursor and the arrow pointer often are oriented so as to cover an underlying tool tip.  Normally, this is not a problem.  However, sometimes you want to see the tool tip but can't.

Is there any way to reorient the cursors so they would no longer overlap the tool tips

Comment: Is it not the other way round? The maker of the app wrongly set the tooltip so it would fall under the cursor. Is this all apps, or just one?

Comment: For me, it's all apps. I have the cursor set slightly larger (since I use the retina screen at full resolution), so it's more of a problem.